# trying to output RSA private key

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

My code:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class Test
{
   public static void Main()
   {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();  

        System.Console.WriteLine(RSA.ToXMLString(false));
   }
}
```

When I run it I get the following:

```
test.cs(10,38): error CS1061: 'RSACryptoServiceProvider' does not contain a definition for 'ToXMLString' and no extension method 'ToXMLString' accepting a first argument of type 'RSACryptoServiceProvider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What I'd kinda expect is something more like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

<RSAParameters xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
      <Modulus>sMFsHSyxAP5N85yvx/XDs9acJa30qwBjoOdDKvNOHJUYBpspwatkdtErCqM2W6tXH9rbvhIn8/nqW4OqAdLinlgkEJoQ/qnzKjYJhHl4YzKFL6Wp+iFRH6ar6ZWOE87LeNQ0nHwlXKoWkJQKV8NB38XRw6aLvNTj8Po2yaFDbQFztsJ+ILkumRh7Leu77IV+124Swc6JqLRt5z2FnDX869dRi2fqcnFa1EHEBsPEndVd2HSeJUncTQiWJ9SNRU+WLltVVewYiGheqr1ABab++3XM5qrB6fWn/RN9Fcg5nM8fachAFSX2YRrEsg7mcbNALRes6OEdpI0LBdX8Wdw6oQ==</Modulus>
    </RSAParameters>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - looks like 4.6.2.

Comment: you have a simple capatilization error, it is `ToXmlString(false)` not `.ToXMLString(false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zseyf239(v=vs.110).aspx

https://www.code4copy.com/csharp/how-to-generate-publicprivate-key-using-rsa/

```
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(RSA.ToXmlString(false));
        }
```